# Civ V and City State Allies

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Ok, i am very far into my game of civ v atm, i have many allies. The problem is with the Byzantinum Empire. It seesms that any city state connected to their borders gains some sort of static influence toward them Byzantium is completly bankrupt and in negative GPT yet every so often they will supplant me as city state ally. In that occasion i will buy back influence.(I have a strong economy) I would just like to understand why this is happenning, if there is some sort of policy or tenent, or something that is specific with the byzantium empire.

Comment: They could've just completed quests for the city state, like clearing barb encampments, connecting a certain resource to the trade network, amass the most culture/faith within a certain period....

Comment: @Kevin this is possible, but it doesnt seem likely as it isnt outputting 40 influence for the civ, and it happens way to often.

Comment: You have all three Civ 5 expansions tagged; which one are you actually playing? And what era are you and Byzantium in?

Comment: RESOLVED: Byzantium has gunboat diplomacy ( they are of the autocracy ideology)

Comment: If you found the answer to your own question, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It can be a result of gunboat diplomacy, but there are other factors that also play a role here, such as:

1. if these city-states share the same religion with Byzantium, their influence decay will be slowed down by 25%;
2. if Byzantium has patronage opener, influence decay will also be slowed down by 25%.

If Byzantium has these factors but you don't, then their influence decays slower than yours, so effectively their influence is gaining every turn relative to yours.